# rsync less verbose logs

Tags: logging, rsync

How do I get rsync to only log the files it backs up?

I don't want these lines filling up my log file which it does every time runs even if it has nothing to send.:

```
2016/11/13 14:30:01 [1554] building file list
2016/11/13 14:30:04 [1554] sent 3255320 bytes  received 6707 bytes  total size 697719781381
```

It's running from a cron, not in daemon mode. My command is:

`rsync -rtbpgo --suffix="."$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M") --exclude=".*" --exclude="~*" --exclude="[Tt][Hh][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ss].[Dd][Bb]" --exclude="[Dd][Ee][Ss][Kk][Tt][Oo][Pp].[Ii][Nn][Ii]" --log-file=/mnt/rsync.log --info=FLIST /mnt/datastore/ /mnt/dsbackup`

Answer (score 3):

Add hese two flags, they should do the trick  `-q -i`   (quiet and items)